# Creating and using calibration factors

Tags: polynomials, factoring, algebraic-curves

Perhaps simple question, but I (the simple) need some guidance.  The following applies to a project ongoing and is a challenge in that I am not a math whiz!

As example, I wish to measure temperature through a sensor whose resistance changes with temperature.  It is a non-linear sensor.  It's easy to create a calibration table which provides two columns, the Actual Temperature and the Resistance Result.  As I am interested in 0-10 Degrees C, my table might consist of three rows:

```
Temperature    Resistance 
__________________________
0 Degrees C    100.4 Ohms
5 Degrees C    110.8 Ohms
10 Degrees C   140.2 Ohms
```

So I have taken three measurements at the bottom, middle, and top of my range.

Now, if I were to plot this, we'd see quite a jump between 5 and 10 C, as the device is not linear.

If under actual conditions I then read 102.0 Ohms, what might the best method be to determine the Temperature at the given resistance?  What about at 115.3 Ohms?  Same method?

Of course, I could say that between 0 and 5 C we have 2.08 Ohms per Degree C, and between 5 and 10 we have 5.88 Ohms per Degree C.  I bet there's a better method that will fit to a curve.

As the higher range is wild, I might have to take a few more calibration steps between these values to get more data.  Seems reasonable.  But what then?  Must I store this table and apply a Ohms per Degree factor if the value is within a particular calibration step range?

Maybe this a good place for the use of a polynomial equation, but I am a bit green here.  Please help with an example as I best learn by that method.  I'm hoping for the best "curve fit" without too much math processing overhead.

Thank you!

Comment: The sensor spec. sheet will typically have a small plot showing the relationship (possibly even a model). Guess the form and then fit measured data to the model. The required accuracy of your model will depend on your application. At worst you could make many measurements and use linear interpolation between points.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to develop my own calibration table.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into polynomial fitting methods, but they will each have their own set of problems.

This could be made worse by more data points, by nonlinear behaviors and a host of other things, so you'll get different mileage.

For the particular example you gave, I used Wolfram Alpha and it provided two approaches that include a [*linear and periodic approach*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+%7B%7B0%2C+100.4%7D%2C+%7B5%2C+110.8%7D%2C+%7B+10%2C+140.2%7D%7D).

If it could have done a least-squares fit, it would have provided that too.

So you can see, not too good. You could try adding another handful of data points and see if it improves things.

I am surprised you can not get the data sheet and see if they provide a temperature based model for this sort of thing.

Comment: @amWhy: As usual, thanks for the support!

Comment: Looking just now.  Thanks.

Comment: @amzoti With my three terms the periodic method seems a mess.  The linear is much better.  I used wild terms as worst case and adjusted and tested to something realistic with good linear result.  Curious how the periodic method would therefore be useful.  Also, how might I solve for the linear method?  Is this where least squares fit in?

Comment: @MarkRichards: This is typically the problem with such methods, they hit points spot on, but depending on many factors, they can be a mess outside those points. You want to look into the [*Curve Fitting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) approaches for the different methods. Regards

Comment: @amzoti: If I use curve fitting (and thanks for the reference) I must make perhaps many measurements to get a proper "curve".  Whereas, with three measurements across a given range, I was hoping for a method that would create a smoothe slope.  Perhaps that slope would be defined by the difference between point 0 and 1, and point 1 and 2?  It seems reasonable that values between the three points would be off, but perhaps the error would not be as great were I to simply use a slope between the three points (creating two slopes)?

Comment: @MarkRichards: Can you use the linear fit equation and experiment with reality and see the types of errors or goodness it provides?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8480/discussion-between-mark-richards-and-amzoti)